# Where are these photos taken

Tags: locations

Does anyone know where these photos were taken:
http://s1296.beta.photobucket.com/user/blue11086/media/NatGeo07_zps3fddea48.jpg.html
http://s1296.beta.photobucket.com/user/blue11086/media/NatGeo04_zps9669a797.jpg.html

Comment: Not sure if that is the only information you want from the picture.

Answer (score 5):

You can search the images in http://images.google.com by providing the url/upload of the image when the image is popular but no geolocation is available.

According result from Google's image search, the first one is likely shoot in Jiuzhaigou, China. The second one is likely shoot in Luoping, China.